# Display add to cart button inline on category page WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to display all of my add to cart buttons "inline" but due to the text being longer on some products it is jumping around. I have tried various fixes but with no luck. 
What is the easiest way to fix this?

I used a CSS to set a min height of the background banner, which fixed part of the issue. But the add to cart buttons still jump around. 
Is it possible to set a relative height or something so they show up at the same place?

**The CSS code I tried** *(but this doesn't really make it look proper either)*:

```html
.woo-product-title {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.woo-product-box {
    min-height: 160px;
}
```

**This is how it looks:**

[image: how it looks]

**This is how it should look:**

[image: how it should look]

I am not very good at advanced coding (primarily know CSS) and the site is built in a theme, so changing major parts of the HTML is not possible. Therefore a CSS option or PHP code for functions.php is prefered.

**This CSS code somewhat fixes the problem, but forces a very large gap on top of some products with short descriptions. Is there any CSS way to make it slightly more welcoming?**

```html
.box-text a:not(.button) { min-height: 90px; }
```

Site is on: http://detitalienskekoekken.dk.linux99.unoeuro-server.com/shop/

Comment: As [WooCommerce templates can be overridden via your active child theme (or active theme)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), this allow you to change the html structure a bit and to make advanced customizations with a mix of CSS. For CSS / Styling help, you should provide a live link…

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much. I did not know this was allowed, this forum is great. Here is the link: http://detitalienskekoekken.dk.linux99.unoeuro-server.com/shop/

Comment: For CSS styling help, there is no other way than live web site link

Comment: Thank you, I see. Do you know of any CSS only option? And if I do have to edit the html how would I go about this? I am assuming it will be somewhere under the WooCommerce folder?

Answer (score 1):

```
.ajax_add_to_cart.add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple.button.primary.is-outline.mb-0.is-small {
margin-top: 20px;
width: 100%;
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
background-color: #c31919;
color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 5px;}
```

Should be CSS Code for the Button.

And rest needs to be done by adjusting the HTML.

Comment: Considering that I have 0 experience with HTML editting and it is built in my theme, what are my best options? Are there any decent CSS only fixes?